# Why does export -p exclude $_ variable?

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

As far I know, there are 3 ways to see exported variables:

```
$ export -p | wc -l
50
$ env | wc -l
51
$ printenv | wc -l
51
```

As you can see, `export -p` misses single variable. It's a `$_` one:

```
$ diff <(export -p |sed 's/declare -x //' | sed 's/"//g' | sort) <(printenv | sort)
41a42
> _=/usr/bin/printenv
```

`$_` is special variable set to final argument of previous command executed. Why `export -p` doesn't include it, unlike two other commands?

**Edit**

I understand that exporting `$_` might not have any sense but if `$_` is not exported then why it appears in `printenv` output? `printenv` prints environment variables, environment variables are exported ones, `$_` is not exported. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_` does not seem to be an environmental variable in `bash`, `bash` only appears to export it into a child process' environment. Inside bash itself it seems to be a normal shell variable. Note however this is not the case when the first command is executed:

```
$ bash -c 'export -p | grep _='
declare -x _="/bin/bash"
```

Afterwards however it shows up as a normal variable:

```
$ bash -c ':; declare -p | grep _='
declare -- BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=":; declare -p | grep _="
declare -- _=":
```

Not this is not the case in `dash`:

```
$ dash -c 'export -p | grep _='
export _='/bin/dash'
$ dash -c ':; export -p | grep _='
export _='/bin/dash'
```

Although here it only seems to take on its proper role in interactive mode:

```
$ dash
$ :
$ export -p | grep _=
export _=':'
```

Answer (score 4):

`export -p` does not show `$_` for the simple reason that the command only shows those variables marked for export, and `$_` (being a special parameter and not a variable--yes, the `bash` documentation makes that distinction) is not marked for export by the shell. While you can assign to `_`, `bash` will overwrite its value after each command. `bash` also seems to prevent, or at least undo, any attempt to explicitly export `_`.

Answer (score 1):

From `help export`:

```
  -p    display a list of all exported variables and functions
```

Which would imply that `$_` is simply not exported. That also makes sense since `$_` is the last argument of the **previous command** exporting it to a separate shell would not be very useful since it will always be automatically reset depending on the last command run.

You can confirm that the commands you tried only list exported variables:

```
$ export -p | wc -l
41
$ foo="bar"
$ export -p | wc -l
41
$ export foo="bar"
$ export -p | wc -l
42
```

To see the full list of currently set variables (exported or not), use `set` with no arguments. This, however, will also list functions so you'll need to filter those out:

```
$ set | grep -P '^\S.*=' | wc -l
83
$ foo=bar
$ set | grep -P '^\S.*=' | wc -l
84
```

Comment: It doesn't have to exported to a separate shell, it is just a question of whether it exists as an environmental or otherwise variable in the current one.

Comment: @Graeme not sure what you mean. `export -p` lists exported variables _only_ and `$_` is not exported.

Comment: '`$_` is the last argument of the previous command exporting it to a separate shell would not be very useful since it will always be automatically reset depending on the last command run.' - this was what I was looking at.

Comment: @Graeme exactly, I don't see the point of exporting that variable to child/separate shells which is, I guess, why it's not exported.

Comment: I understand that exporting `$_` might not have any sense but if `$_` is not exported then why it appears in `printenv` output? `printenv` prints environment variables, environment variables are exported ones, `$_` is not exported. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Nykakin I don't have a particularly deep knowledge of this, my answer is just the result of my findings. If you're lucky one of the real shell gurus will weigh in here eventually. However, I'm not at all sure that environment variables are exported by definition.

Comment: @terdon, sorry that was a rushed explanation. What I am saying is that if you start a subshell (ie with `()`), then it gets all the same variables as the parent. Here doesn't matter if it is exported or not. If you run an external program (ie `env`, `printenv` or another shell invoked directly), then it is put into the child's environment anyway (eg via `execle`).